# SQL Server 2000 command line utility

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is there anything like the SQL 2005 SQLCMD for SQL 2000?  I need to run updates/deletes in an unattended mode.

Answer (score 2):

[osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213090(SQL.80).aspx) and [isql](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/MSSQL/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_1.shtml) will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

`osql` and `isql`

See the MSDN docs on [osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28SQL.80%29.aspx) or [isql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214007%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for details and what parameters they support.